# Mockito - verify condition inside a method that is supposed to throw error

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following code that I'm trying to test:

**class foo:**

```
public void myFunction(Business business) {
  ...
  if(someCondition) {
    disconnect(business);
    throw exception("message");
  }
}

public void disconnect(Business business) {
  ...
  myService.expireTokens(business);
  ...
}
```

**foo test:**

```
@Test
public void test(){
  Assert.assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {
    service.myFunction(business);
    verify(myService, times(1)).expireTokens(any());
  });
}
```

So the problem above is that I can comment out the **disconnect()** in my if clause and the assertThrows would 'catch' the erorr / pass the test, and if the normal flow goes through, it would still throw the expected error and pass, how can I test the nested disconnect actually went through before throwing?

Comment: what does `disconnect()` do? does it call some service so that you can provide a mock and verify a specific method from the mock has been called?

Comment: move out verify() from lambda to test()

Answer (score 1):

Move `verify(myService, times(1)).expireTokens(any())` out of the `Assert.assertThrows` function context.

`Assert.assertThrows` equal next construction:

```java
        try {
              //run exceptional operation
              service.myFunction(business);
              //code after exceptional operation will not be executed
              verify(myService, times(1)).expireTokens(any());
        } catch (Throwable actualThrown) {
            if (expectedThrowable.isInstance(actualThrown)) {
                return actualThrown;                
            } else {
                throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
```

So the code defined after the exceptional function will not be executed because of raised exception. This is the reason of the incorrect test behavior.

Example of the correct test implementation:

```java
    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyService myService = mock(MyService.class);
        TestService testService = new TestService(myService);
        Business business = new Business();

        Assert.assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {
            testService.myFunction(business);
        });

        verify(myService, times(1)).expireTokens(any());
    }

public class TestService {

    private MyService myService;

    public TestService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public void myFunction(Business business) throws Exception {
        if(business != null) {
            disconnect(business);
            throw new Exception("message");
        }
    }

    public void disconnect(Business business) {
        myService.expireTokens(business);
    }
}

public class MyService {
    public void expireTokens(Business business) {
    }
}
```